# All classes with particular Interface should be notify by event

Tags: c#, interface

How,does one should call an event declared by interface so that all the classes that has implemented that interface get notified??

For example in structure like this,

```
public delegate void myDel(int value);

interface IEventCaller{
event myDel myDelEventCall;
}


public Class One : IEventCaller {

public event myDel myDelEventCall;



}


public Class Two : IEventCaller {

public event myDel myDelEventCall;

}
```

I want both class One and Two to get notify and act as event gets called, I am feeling somewhere I am going wrong direction , is it possible to do?

Comment: You need to register all those objects somewhere, so that the code that "needs to inform all objects" has somewhere to go to find all those objects.

Comment: you don't - you use a base-class instead of an interface for this

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen any example ?

Comment: @CarstenKönig I am developing game using Unity3D and there Mono class is mandatory to have as a base class so No I can have base class

Comment: of course you can - your base class can have one too ;)

Comment: Unity3D has default Mono class on all classes we create,and that mono may have one base class on its own, so that would not be good idea to mess up with default behavioral for just one problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you want doesn't involve events. Events would be used by an object implementing `IEventCaller` to notify some object holding a reference to that object of some change. To invoke something on the object implementing `IEventCaller` would just require a method, for example `Hello()`;

First, you need code that informs all the objects that implement this interface. To make that possible, you somewhere need to store a list of instances that *want* to get notified.

One solution would be to create a class that manages that list. Let's say like this

```
private static List<IEventCaller> eventCallers = new List<IEventCaller>();

public static void AddEventCaller(IEventCaller c)
{
    eventCallers.Add(c);
}

public static void RemoveEventCaller(IEventCaller c)
{
    eventCallers.Remove(c);
}

public static IEventCaller[] EventCallers
{
    get { return eventCallers.ToArray() }
}
```

Of course this code needs to be thread safe, etc. I'd put all this into a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) to be globally available.

Then, all objects that implement `IEventCallers` need to register/unregister accordingly. Thus, I'd also have them Implement `IDisposable` so that in the constructor you can do

```
public EventCallable()
{
     Singleton.Instance.AddEventCaller(this);
}
```

and in the `Dispose` method you can do this:

```
public void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    Singleton.Instance.RemoveEventCaller(this);
}
```

Now the code that should notify every instance could just do this:

```
public void NotifyAll()
{
    foreach (IEventCaller caller in Singleton.Instance.EventCallers)
        caller.Hello();
}
```

Comment: Wow you beauty , Open up my mind to broad possibilities I can do with interface ,great, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking at this the other one around.

With events, you want to have an object which is the *publisher*, which is responsible for publishing the event and saying *"hey guys, something just occurred and you should know about it"*, and you have your subscribers, which are the guys who say *"Yo dawg, let me know when that thing occurs, so i can act on it"*.

What you can do is have the object which is responsible for the event occurring implement your interface:

```
public class Publisher : IEventCaller
{
    public event MyDel MyDeleteEvent;
    public void OnDeleteOccured()
    {
        var myDeleteEvent = MyDeleteEvent;
        if (myDeleteEvent != null)
        {
            MyDeleteEvent(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And then have your `One` and `Two` objects register to that event occurring, where they pass a method which signature matches the delegate type of `MyDel`:

```
public class SubscriberOne
{
    public void OnSomethingOccured(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

public class SubscriberTwo
{
    public void OnSomethingOccured(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

And the registration goes:

```
void Main()
{
    var publisher = new Publisher();
    var subscriberOne = new SubscriberOne();
    var subscriberTwo = new SubscriberTwo();

    publisher.MyDeleteEvent += subscriberOne.OnSomethingOccured;
    publisher.MyDeleteEvent += subscriberTwo.OnSomethingOccured;
}
```

Comment: I guess then interface is not at all needed in this case? I can just define delegates and events in publisher while subscribers will notify as we call them?

Comment: You're guess is right. If you only have one publisher at the moment, then encapsulating the event inside him would be even better. Note, instead of creating your own delegate type, you can use built in .NET delegates. Your delegate would be equivalent to an `Action<int>`.

Comment: yes I know about Actions and Func<> though not quite sure how events can be created from delegate type Action

Something like following?

    'Action<int> myDelegate;

    myDelegate event myEvent

    myEvent(myInteger);'

Comment: By simply saying: `public event Action<int> MyEvent(int myInteger);` No need to declare the `Action` a field.